# nested messages in html

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to build a simple messages fourm.

I want to nest the messages (answer to question)

My site is in hebrew (`dir="rtl"`)

I thought to create `<ol>` dynmically for every answer\question

meaning:

> 1.q1
>
> 1.1 a1
>
> 1.2 a2
>
> 1.2.1 a2-a1

how can I do this and keep the direction `rtl`?

Comment: If I understand this correctly you would want the questions/answers to cascade from right to left?  If this is the case it would be just like doing it left to right except instead of padding/margin on the left you would be placing the appropriate padding on the righthand side.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The markup of the nested `ol`s should be as follows:

```
<ol>
    <li>Question 1
        <ol>
            <li>Answer 1</li>
            <li>Answer 2</li>
            <li>Answer 3
                <ol>
                    <li>Answer 3.1</li>
                </ol>
            </li>
        </ol>
    </li>
    <li>Question 2</li>
    <li>Question 3</li>
</ol>
```

As far as I know there is no difference in this markup whether it's `rtl` or `ltr` languages, correct me if I'm wrong :)

Comment: The DOM should technically be the same. The CSS on the other hand would probably be floated to the right, and padded as Jrod above mentioned.

Comment: @wachpwnski Yes, I do agree) but lack of experience with `rtl` gave me doubts)) Thanks